# how to order a JSON response based on database relationship using eloquent

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm quite new to Laravel and I'm trying to figure out how to properly work with Eloquent so far so good, but I'm stuck in something I want to do:

I have 3 tables in a database well 4 if you count the migrations one: food, food_group and portions which food_group and portion have the same structure which is and id as primary key and a name columns

the food ones have

```
 |  id(primary)  |  name  | food_group_id (foreign key) | portion_id (foreign key |
```

all good because I have a nice formatted JSON with this in my route

```
Route::get('/read', function() {

$categories = App\FoodGroup::with('Foods')->get();

 return Response::json(array('data' => $categories));
});

data: [
    {
       id: 1,
       name: "Frutas",
       foods: [
               {
                   id: 18,
                   name: "Acelga",
                   cant_portion: 2
               },
               {
                   id: 19,
                   name: "Espinaca",
                   cant_portion: 2
               },
              ]
    }
 ]
```

and if I change the App\FoodGroup with App\Portion it gives me the same array but now ordered as the Foreign Key Portion

what I need is to first order with FoodGRoup and inside each item of the FFo_group one, now ordered by the second Foreign key which is Portion so I can have something like this

```
data: [
    {
       id: 1,
       name: "Frutas",
       portions:[
           id: 18,
           name: "Gr",  
           foods: [
               {
                   id: 18,
                   name: "Acelga",
                   cant_portion: 2
               },
               {
                   id: 19,
                   name: "Espinaca",
                   cant_portion: 2
               },
            ]
       ]           
    }
 ]
```

Comment: $categories = App\FoodGroup::with('Foods','Portions')->get(); What about this ??

Comment: @Drudgethat won't work cause Portions its not in the model of FoodGroup, i can do App\FoodGroup::with('Foods.portion')->get(); and it gives me on each item the values of the table portions but i i just want one array of the value portions and in that array order them, i dont knwo if im clear enough

Comment: can you show the table for food_group and portion

Comment: Hi @oseintow http://i.imgur.com/giFr0TP.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your expected JSON shows `foods` as a child of `portions`. In order to do this, you need to setup this relationship.

On your `Portion` model, you need to setup the following relationship:

```
public function foods() {
    return $this->hasMany(Food::class);
}
```

With this relationship setup, you can now get your data like this:

```
$categories = App\FoodGroup::with('portions.foods')->get();
```

This will load your food groups, then it will load the portions into the food groups, and then it will load the foods into the portions.

### Edit

I may have slightly misread your question. I assumed you had a `portions` relationship defined on `\App\FoodGroup`. If not, you can add this like so:

FoodGroup:

```
public function portions() {
    // the second parameter is the name of the pivot table.
    // in this case, your foods table connects your portions and food groups.
    return $this->belongsToMany(Portion::class, 'foods')->distinct();
}
```

### Edit 2

This solution is a little hacky because it is treating the `foods` table as a pivot table, though it wasn't specifically designed for that. Because of this, there are multiple entries in the `foods` table that contain the same key pair values, and this is why you're getting duplicate related models.

If you throw a `distinct()` onto the relationship, this should take care of the issue, as it will eliminate the duplicates created from the inner join. The code above has been modified.

Comment: I think you got the idea of what i want, one thing i tried the code as you put it and it didnt work i guess i should changue the  class thibg to something else? cause i get a BadMethodCallException in Builder::portions()

Comment: @AllanAlvarezOrtiz I have updated my answer based on your comment.

Comment: Yes! that's what i want but, it repeats every item i mean it does it correctly http://i.imgur.com/Xjuvl4L.png i mean if there are 10 items inside the portion object it creates 10 lists of portions i only need 1

Comment: actually it does it randomly see the Json here: http://codebeautify.org/jsonviewer/cb9a9d16

Comment: @AllanAlvarezOrtiz I have updated my answer based on your comments.

Comment: thank you @patricus it works nicely, marked as correct answer!

Comment: Hi @patricus, i just realized that the solution was indeed hacky, it all works great just 1 tiny thing is that,in every portion array, it gives me all the items that have that portion, for example in FoodGroup 'fruits', with a 'cup' portion it gives the fruits that have that portion, and the vegetables, and the beef, i just want the items of each foodgroup

Answer (score 1):

Based on the picture(ie your tables) you sent food_group does not have direct relationship with the portions so you can't chain food_group with portion like this

```
  App\FoodGroup::with('portion.foods')
```

it should rather be (that is why you getting BadMethodCallException in Builder::portions())

```
 App\FoodGroup::with('foods.portion')
```

because foodgroup has many foods and foods has many portion. so you can try something like this

```
App\FoodGroup::with(['foods.portion'=>function($q){
   $q->orderBy('id')
}])->get();
```

Comment: Thank you for the help, not precisley but close, what i want is look at my json right now: http://i.imgur.com/JzYcWoz.png you see how in each item i have a portion array and it duplciates every time a new item appears, what i want is instead of duplciate just put in once and inside get all the items that match that portion

Comment: Loading 'foods.portion' does not give the structure that has been requested. This will have the portion objects inside the food objects. OP has requested the food objects inside the portion objects.

Comment: Additionally, because of the way eager loading works, you can't specify a limit inside the eager loading constraints (which is done with `take(1)`). This won't limit the load to one food per food group, this will limit the load to one food period. If there are 1000 food groups, this will still only load 1 food record total, not the expected 1000.

Comment: Yes i can only use  App\FoodGroup::with('foods.portion') that the array i got, and the one y send to you, so no way i cand achieve what i want? cause the solution keeos saying me its an unexpected '}' wich i found weird

Comment: @patricus i tested the code before posting i didn't just post. You can try and laravel will limit it for you. The take(1) really works inside the eager loading

Comment: @oseintow You're not going to get an error or anything. The code and the query are going to run just fine. It's just that you're only going to eager load one record total. Make sure you're testing with more than just one or two records so you can see the consequences.

Comment: Yea that is what he want just that its unfortunate his relationship makes it difficult to get exactly what he wants. He wants the inverse of foods.portion which his relationship does not permit

Comment: well and what relationship do you suggest?

Comment: @oseintow I think there is still a misunderstanding here. Say there are 10 foodgroup records, and they are related to 100 food records. If you add a limit to the eager load of the food records, it will load all 10 foodgroup records, but only load 1 food record total. Not 1 food record per foodgroup (which would be 10 food records total), but only 1 food record total. So, one of the foodgroup records would have it's related food, but the other 9 will have empty collections.

Comment: @AllanAlvarezOrtiz Thinking of a way to resolve this. Don't want you to change your table structure or your relationship. Because you understand your project more

Comment: I have no prolem in changing the the relationship, what i want in the end is , with the json build an <UL> in wich the title of UL is the food_group, and then inside another <UL's> for each kind of portion and then list the food item, i though mi relationship was the best way to do it, but u have any suggestion?

Comment: @oseintow the answer patricus gave, works but as i answered on his reply, it gives multiple item clones, and i just need one, in his reply i have put the result JSON with his method.

Comment: change the return $this->belongsToMany(Portion::class, 'foods'); to return $this->belongsTo(Portion::class, 'foods'); and see how it goes.

Comment: @oseintow it says: Illegal offset type in isset or empty

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104498/discussion-between-allan-alvarez-ortiz-and-oseintow).