# how to get only matching items in json parent on laravel eloquent

Tags: php, mysql, json, laravel

so following my other question [how to order a json response based on database relationship using eloquent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35618567/how-to-order-a-json-response-based-on-database-relationship-using-eloquent/35619028#35619028)

t all works great just 1 tiny thing is that,in every portion array, it gives me all the items that have that portion, for example in FoodGroup 'fruits', with a 'cup' portion it gives the fruits that have that portion, and the vegetables, and the beef, i just want the items of each foodgroup

```
{
  id: 1,
  name: "Fruits",
  portions: [
                {
                 id: 1,
                 name: "Pieza",
                 foods: [
                          {
                             id: 1,
                             name: "Apple",
                             cant_portion: 2,
                             portion_name: "Pieza",
                             food_group_name: "Fruit"
                           },
                           {
                             id: 1,
                             name: "Tomatoe",
                             cant_portion: 2,
                             portion_name: "Pieza",
                             food_group_name: "Veggie"
                           }
                        ]
                },
            ]
 },
 {
   id:2,
   name:"Veggies"
   portions:[]
  }
```

As you see, the veggie one should'nt be there, it should be in second item of the parents json, now it doesnt return an empty portion as i illustrated there, it gives me all the food in every ones but i just want the ones that correspond to their group

Comment: What about showing how you are creating the Json?

Comment: @MartinHenriksen the models and images of the code are in the other question that i link in the post