# Rearrange a JSON object in angularjs to create a nested ul

Tags: html, angularjs, laravel

Hi i have an RESTfulAPI that return a JSON object like this:

```
{
data: [
       {
        id: 4,
        name: "Naranja",
        cant_portion: 2,
        portion_name: "Piezas",
        foodgroup_name: "Frutas"
        }
      ]
}
```

and i want to rearrange it so i can have something like this:

```
{
data: [
       {
        foodgroup_name: "Frutas",
        items:[
               {
               portion_name: "Piezas",
               items:[
                      {
                      id: 4,
                      name: "Naranja",
                      cant_portion: 2,
                      }
                     ]
               }
              ]            
        }
      ]
}
```

the idea of doing this is that i want to have a nested ul and the first ul should give me the name of the foodgroup, then the next ul should give the type of portions that foodgroup has, and inside that ul to put some li, with the items that match those 2 requirements.

Now in my API i can return the name of each Food group, so i'm ok with that first ul but in the second one where the portions goes, not every foodgroup has all of the portions, just maybe 1 or 2.

Comment: Can we use jquery for the solution?

Comment: You add Laravel tag in your question, so why we don't use it to make easier?

Comment: @Reddy I prefer not, but it will help

Comment: @rome웃 any idea on how to do it in laravel? cause, the tables are 3: food, foodgroup, and portions an wich food has 2 foreging keys one for each other column, i've already tried to do it without any succes, here i have a related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35618567/how-to-order-a-json-response-based-on-database-relationship-using-eloquent

Comment: Are items the same level with foodgroup_name a food, and with each item in this, get portions and food corresponding to portions?

Comment: I don't want to use DB relationship, can you post your data, i will rearrange it for u?

Comment: @rome웃 what data do u need? in the post i put the array i get with just 1 item, here is the full json object: http://codebeautify.org/jsonviewer/cb91851a

Comment: Check my final edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check it:

```
private function _rearrangeData($data = array())
{
    $out = array();
    if (!count($data)) {
        return $data;
    }
    $foodgroup = array();
    $portion = array();
    $foodgroup_name = $data[0]['foodgroup_name'];
    $portion_name = $data[0]['portion_name'];
    foreach ($data as $item) {
        if ($item['foodgroup_name'] == $foodgroup_name) {
            if ($item['portion_name'] == $portion_name) {
                unset($item['foodgroup_name']);
                unset($item['portion_name']);
                array_push($portion, $item);
            } else {
                $arr = [
                    'portion_name' => $portion_name,
                    'items' => $portion
                ];
                $portion_name = $item['portion_name'];
                unset($item['foodgroup_name']);
                unset($item['portion_name']);
                $portion = [$item];
                array_push($foodgroup, $arr);
            }
        } else {
            $arr = [
                'portion_name' => $portion_name,
                'items' => $portion
            ];
            array_push($foodgroup, $arr);

            $arr = [
                'foodgroup_name' => $foodgroup_name,
                'items' => $foodgroup
            ];
            $foodgroup_name = $item['foodgroup_name'];
            $portion_name = $item['portion_name'];
            unset($item['foodgroup_name']);
            unset($item['portion_name']);
            $portion = [$item];
            $foodgroup = [];
            array_push($out, $arr);
        }
    }
    $arr = [
        'portion_name' => $portion_name,
        'items' => $portion
    ];
    array_push($foodgroup, $arr);
    $arr = [
        'foodgroup_name' => $foodgroup_name,
        'items' => $foodgroup
    ];
    array_push($out, $arr);
    return $out;
}
```

**Edit:** with your db:

```
$food_group = DB::table('foods')->join('food_group', 'food_group.id', '=', 'foods.food_group_id')->groupBy('food_group_id')->get();
$out = [];
foreach ($food_group as $item) {
     $foods = DB::table('foods')->join('portions', 'portions.id', '=', 'foods.portion_id')->where('food_group_id', $item->id)->groupBy('portion_id')->get();
     $arr1 = [];
     foreach($foods as $item2) {
          $por_food = DB::table('foods')->where('food_group_id',$item->id)->where('portion_id',$item2->id)->get();
          $arr = [
              'portion_name' => $item2->name,
              'items' => $por_food
          ];
          array_push($arr1, $arr);
     }
     $arr2 = [
           'foodgroup_name'=>$item->name,
           'items'=>$arr1
     ];
     array_push($out, $arr2);
}
return response()->json(['data'=>$out],200);
```

Comment: woow i'm really impress that's some nice code there D:, just one thing how can i implmented in my controller? cause in order to get the array i give to you i make like this: return response()->json(['data' => Food::all()],200)

Comment: Add above function then change `Food::all()` to `$this->_rearrangeData(Food::all())`

Comment: You are my hero, one more question tho, with DB relationship would it be faster? cause this kinda slow .-.

Comment: I've realized it's a nice approach but it repetas some itme, for example the one that that says: "cereales sin grasa" repetas several times the portion "Tazas" and "Piezas"

Comment: You can sort data before use above code :), i can't understand ur db relationship so i have no idea rearrange it by Laravel, btw, i'm not sure it make them faster or not

Comment: ya i'm understand ur db relationship now, can you export 3 table to .sql file?

Comment: Yes indeed it was faster! you sir are AWESOME! mark as correct answer thank you very very much!